# Upgrade php 5.2 to php 5.3 on debian etch

Tags: php, php5, debian-etch

I have a vps server that is in production currently.
I need to upgrade my current php 5.2 to php 5.3.

I have found the repositories here http://www.dotdeb.org

My question is how do I upgrade, keeping my current configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You need only to add the repositories from dotdeb on the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Then use `aptitude` to reload the sources and check the php packages you have.

If the packages are correctly done, you should not lose any config, since configuration files are not overwritten during updates: if there's a conflict dpkg will ask what to do and you can choose to override or just save the new version with a different extension.

After that, just check the README.Debian on `/usr/share/doc/` package documentation to see if there's anything else to complete the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all

gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 89DF5277
gpg -a --export 89DF5277 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now we have to update 
apt-get update

Then you can easily upgrade..

and restart apache, and test if everything is working , by checking phpinfo()
btw..how did you install php previously ?? if you had compiled it manually ..the above method is not the best way ..

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported by DotDeb

> For your information, I do NOT intend to publish PHP>=5.3.0 packages
>   for Debian Etch, it would mean too much work to get clean packages…
>   PHP 5.2.10 (once fixed) will be last version available for Etch from
>   Dotdeb. Then, you’re strongly encouraged to migrate to Debian Lenny if
>   you want to take profit from 5.3.0.

[Source](http://www.dotdeb.org/2009/07/03/php-5-3-0-final-preview-packages-available-for-debian-lenny/)