# How to upgrade PHP 5.2.0 on Debian Etch?

Tags: php, debian, debian-etch

How do I upgrade from PHP 5.2.0 to anything > PHP 5.2.3 on Debian Etch? Do I need to use [backports](http://backports.debian.org/news/Etch_Backports_removed_from_backports.debian.org/) (not quite sure how to do it)? I tried [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org/), but they don't support Etch. I'd like to upgrade to the latest 5.3.*, but I will be content with anything > 5.2.3.

My current `sources.list`:

`deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main`

Many thanks for any insight.

**EDIT:**

For reference, [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/165791/upgrade-php-5-2-to-php-5-3-on-debian-etch) was no help because of the dotdeb.org note I made above.

Comment: It is time to upgrade.  The is no longer any official security updates for etch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Backports (for Etch) only has 5.2.0 anyway:

```
# apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.3.6-11
  Version table:
     5.3.6-11 0
        800 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
     5.2.0+dfsg-8+etch16 0
        500 http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch/main amd64 Packages
```

I checked this by first adding the Debian Backports source to my list:

`deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports/ etch-backports main`

You should probably upgrade to Lenny or try to install [Lenny's package](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/php5), perhaps using [APT pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html).

Comment: Since upgrading isn't an option, I'll give APT pinning a try. Never heard of it, but after reading the page, it looks like it's what I'm after.

Comment: BTW, +1 for the APT pinning link. ;)